# apache2 Path rewrite to Get Parameter - Make Slashes work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

The following is my current `.htaccess` file. If I open `https://example.com/test` and it doesn't end with one of the endings specified in line 2, it will open `https://example.com/index.php?url=test`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|php|svg|gif|webm|webp|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, if I try to open `https://example.com/something/test`, it just opens `?url=something` instead of `?url=something/test`. How can I achieve this? I have absolutely no knowledge about regex stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `^([^/]+)/?` only captures the first path segment, ie. `[^/]+` matches 1 or more non-slash characters. If you wish to match the entire URL-path then use `(.+)` (to match 1 or more *any* characters). However, you can be more restrictive if you only want to match say 1 or 2 path segments?

> and it doesn't end with one of the endings specified in line 2

That condition doesn't specifically check that the *URL* "ends" with one of those extensions, it checks that one of those extensions are contained within the filesystem path that the URL maps to. You need an end-of-string anchor `$` at the end of the regex. And to specifically check the URL, you should check against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.

So, this becomes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|php|svg|gif|webm|webp|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That htaccess file works. Thank you very much.